# Using int as seed to generate a 50:50 split

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Imagine have a sample of ints [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]. I want to be able to pass these integers into a method that will split the values into a 50:50 split in order to split the ids into two groups (A and B) and guarantee that I will get the same result every time.

```
var ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

foreach (var id in ids)
{
    var rand = new Random(id);
    Console.WriteLine(rand.Next());
}
```

The code above seems to generate consistent values using the randomizer, however I have two problems with it.

- According to .NET docs, *The implementation of the random number generator in the Random class isn't guaranteed to remain the same across major versions of the .NET Framework. As a result, you shouldn't assume that the same seed will result in the same pseudo-random sequence in different versions of the .NET Framework.* which means I will not be guaranteed the same results after a .NET framework/core update.
- What can I do to the results to figure out whether if the seed belongs to group A or B?

Comment: I'm puzzled. Why would you use a *random* number generator to produce a *consistent* result? Why not use an algorithm that inherently divides the numbers in 2 groups, e.g. just alternate 1st => A, 2nd => B, 3rd => A, ...?

Comment: Take the code source of the Random class and use it? This way you don't depend on the .NET version

Comment: Or get a Mersenne Twister (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) implementation and use that. @jeroenh: The reason to use a pseudo random number like this is that you get repeatable randomness. The contents if the sets are random, but the repeatability is useful for things like testing

Comment: @Flydog57 I get that, but the problem doesn't seem to warrant that. Then again, the description probably describes only part of the problem. Oh well.

Comment: @Flydog57 is correct, I need repeatable randomness dividing the numbers in 2 groups doesn't give me a truly random data set, there may be variables making the split predictable, such as if the list was sorted.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I typed out the method by hand, but yes there should be a new there.